# DSNUTILB using PRESORTED option

Tags: db2, load, db2-zos

I'm working on changing a DSNUTILB parameter member to allow for the input data
now being pre-sorted in order to improve efficiency.
However experiencing syntax issues with incorporating PRESORTED option.

At the moment I have:

```
LOAD DATA PRELOAD LOAD ORDER PRESORTED LOG NO
```

and get this error message

> INVALID OPERAND 'PRELOAD' FOR KEYWORD 'LOAD'

(have tried various permutations)

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Have you looked at the Db2-knowledge centre for your (unspecified) version of Db2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `PRELOAD` is a valid keyword. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/ugref/src/tpc/db2z_loadsyntax.html) is a syntax reference for the LOAD utility. I'm assuming here you are using DB2 for z/OS. My link is for version 12.

You'll probably want to have a SYSIN that looks something like:

```
LOAD DATA INDDN SYSREC01
KEEPDICTIONARY  
RESUME NO REPLACE  
PRESORTED YES  
ENFORCE CONSTRAINTS
LOG NO NOCOPYPEND                                                    
EBCDIC CCSID(0037)                                                    

INTO TABLE abc.xyx (
   ... table definition here...
)
```

You can have an `UNLOAD` utility create the SYSIN for you with something like:

```
UNLOAD  TABLESPACE  
EXECUTE NO                     
OPTIONS LOADOPT (                                  
 KEEPDICTIONARY 
 RESUME NO REPLACE  
 PRESORTED YES    
 ENFORCE CONSTRAINTS 
 LOG NO NOCOPYPEND
)            
LOADINDDN YES  LOCK NO  QUIESCE NO                 
  SELECT * FROM abc.xyz
FORMAT  DSNTIAUL  
LOADDDN SYSCTL01  
OUTDDN SYSREC01
```

It will write the load statement to the `SYSREC01` data set.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, that seems to work ok. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dingbats99 if you found the answer useful, an upvote and marking it as the accepted answer would be greatly appreciated (you can find both of these on the left side of the answer) :)